# URLMonitor is not detecting when internet is not available in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, flex3

```
public static var iStatus:Boolean;

public static function initMonitor():void 
{
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.nature.com') ;
    url.method = "HEAD";
    _monitor = new URLMonitor(url);
    _monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, announceStatus);
    _monitor.pollInterval = 1000;
    _monitor.start();

}

public static function  announceStatus(event:StatusEvent):void 
{
    if(_monitor.available)
    {
        iStatus=true;
    }
    else
    {
        iStatus=false;
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I initially run the app with no internet connection, it returns a status of `false`. If I turn on the internet connection, it return a status of `true`. But, if I turn off the internet connection again, it does not return a status of `false`. At that point, it's not entering the `announceStatus` method.

I think `announceStatus` should get called every time the internet connection turns on or off, but it's not working like that. Any suggestions will be helpfull.

Comment: I just tested the code and it seems to be working fine. I can start it up, turn the connection off/on and I see it changing `iStatus` via the `announceStatus` method. How are you disconnecting/reconnecting the internet connection?

Comment: @Marcela you add one break point there in method announceStatus and then turn on the internet connection you will see that control will come to that break point,Now turn off the connection and see control will not come there.this is the problem... when we turn off the internet connection then there is status change, so announceStatus method should get called.but this is not happening.

Comment: I followed your steps as you listed them, and I had absolutely no issues. The breakpoint was triggered every time there was a change in connection. Once again, how are you turning your internet connection off/on?

Comment: @Marcela Thanks for the response,I am turning on and off through proxy.in IE tools->internet options->connection-->LAN settings there I m turning off and on "Use a proxy server for your LAN" option

Comment: you might want to try enabling/disabling your LAN adapter ("change adapter settings" from the Network & Sharing Center")

Answer (score 0):

```
public static var iStatus:Boolean;

public static function initMonitor():void 
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.NETWORK_CHANGE, onNetworkChange);
    onNetworkChange();
}

protected function onNetworkChange(e:Event):void
{
    _monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest('http://www.nature.com'));
    _monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, announceStatus);
    _monitor.pollInterval = 1000;
    _monitor.start();
}

public static function announceStatus(event:StatusEvent):void 
{
    if(_monitor.available)
    {
        iStatus=true;
    }
    else
    {
        iStatus=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation of your changes.